# Replace 2 (and more) line breaks with \n with java

Tags: java, string, line

I need to replace all line breaks to \n. 
The problem is that if the string contains any characters different from newline, i need to add to beginning of line 4 spaces and \n

Example:

```
The fat
cat



sat on the
mat
```

What I need:

```
\n    The fat\n    cat\n\n\n\nsat on the\n    mat
```

When I use String.replace method, I got this

```
\n    The fat\n    cat\n    \n    \n    sat on the\n    mat
```

Comment: *"i need to add to **beginning** of line 4 spaces"* But your example shows you adding 4 spaces to the **end** of the lines, not the beginning.

Comment: Oh... Sorry... By mistake I attached the wrong sample. Question edited

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("[ \t]*\\R[ \t]*", "\n    ")`. See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/L8cg3B/1) for demo.

Comment: Why does "sat on the" not get 4 spaces before it?

Comment: @Andreas It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replaceAll( "(^|\n)(\\w)", "\n    $2" ).replaceAll( "\n", "\\\\n" )`